# Laravel agroup data by idParent

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel to make a api and now I need help to agroup records in my table companies.

I use this code to make get data:

```
Company::orderBy('created_at')
         ->get();
```

And this result this data:

```
id | idParent | companyName
1  | null     | Company A
2  | 1        | Company B
3  | null     | Company C
4  | 3        | Company D
5  | 1        | Company E
6  | 3        | Company F
```

How can I get the data agroup by idParent like this:

```
id | idParent | companyName
1  | null     | Company A
2  | 1        | Company B
5  | 1        | Company E
3  | null     | Company C
4  | 3        | Company D
6  | 3        | Company F
```

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have the relationship method in place ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I store in the same table companies and branches. I leave idParent null when companies and put id of parent company in idParent when branche. And now I need get this data ordering like second exemple, company with id = 1 is a company, company id = 2 and 5 is a branche of company id=1. Company with id = 3 is a company, company id=4 and 6 is a branche of company id = 3.

Comment: all that was clear from your question. In your `Company::class` model, did you declare the relation between a parent company and a child company ? Also, add the code that you tried and the issues you encountered.

Comment: In fact, I don't want branches to be included in an array within companies. I would like it to be a single array with all companies, ordered as I mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible to define the relationship and the records to be included in the same array?

Comment: if you specificly want that structure, then call all companies and reorder them by code because there is not out of the box way to do it with a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this like below:

```
$companies = Company::where('idParent', null)
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->get();  

$newCompanies = array();

foreach ($companies as $key => $value) {
    $newCompanies[] = $value;
    foreach (Company::where('idParent', $value->id)->orderBy('created_at')->get() as $key => $value) {
        $newCompanies[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the result you want, it's not grouping by it's sorting by,
You could use:

```
return Company::orderBy('idParent')
```

Comment: Rateb thanks for you reply.. This solution will put first idParent null, after idParent = 1 and after idParent = 3. I need order by idParent like second exemple